# Why are index funds called index funds?

Tags: mutual-funds, terminology, index-fund

Why are index funds called index funds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they track an *index*.

Edited: The definition of the word in this case meaning "something used or serving to point out; a sign, token, or indication" from [Meaning  #3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/index)

I presume therefore you are asking what an index is?

There are many variations of what makes up an [Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_market_index) but in short it is a representation of some part of a market.

An extremely simplistic calculation would be to take a basket of stocks, and sum their prices.  If one stock moves up a dollar, and one moves down a dollar, the index has effectively not changed, as it is presumed that the loss in one is offset by the gain in the other.

Comment: I know _what_ an index is, I just don't understand why it's named the way it is. I am not a native English speaker, so that may have something to do with it, but the way I understand the word index (from mathematics or computer science) doesn't explain to me why an index is named thus.

Comment: Added a definition link above: index points to something, in this case, using a subset of stocks to point to the overall performance of the market.

Comment: @ripper234: Imagine the *index* at the back of the book, that points to the most relevant concepts in the book.  Similarly, a stock *index* attempts to point at the most relevant stocks in the market, or a specific sector.

Comment: Indexes aren't managed?